# MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP and national characters

Tags: utf-8, vbscript, serverxmlhttp, punycode

This question is related to this one: [Character encoding Microsoft.XmlHttp in Vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238151/character-encoding-microsoft-xmlhttp-in-vbscript), but differs in one thing, the national characters are in the domain name, not only arguments.

The task is: download a page from the given URL.

I already solved problem of passing UTF8 string into VBScript by reading it from UTF8 encoded file through ADO.

But now when I try opening it MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP returns error: The URL is invalid.

Here is VBScript code:

```
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.CharSet = "utf-8"
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile("fileWithURL.txt")
url = objStream.ReadText()
objStream.Close

Set XMLHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
XMLHttpReq.Open "GET", url, False
XMLHttpReq.send
WEBPAGE = XMLHttpReq.responseText
```

If you put something like *hxxp://россия.рф/main/page5.html* into the UTF8 encoded fileWithURL.txt the script will raise an error while working ok with *hxxp://google.com*.

The workaround is to use ascii representation of the domain name - but I yet haven't found PunnyCode encoder for vbscript (apart from [Chillkat](https://www.example-code.com/vbscript/punycode.asp) which is an overkill for my task).

Will appreciate your help on the main problem or workaround.

Comment: There is nothing built in to do this you would have to either try and build the decode / encode algorithm yourself *(bear in mind VBScript doesn't play nice with byte level stuff)* or take the hit and use something like [ChillkatSoft](https://www.example-code.com/vbscript/punycode.asp) or [Motobit ByteArray](http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/cm440.htm) COM components to do the heavy-lifting for you.

Comment: Thank you for fast response! So it really doesn't work because it shouldn't - is it correct? In other words, MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP does not support national characters in domain names, does it? Which one of two  proposed encoders would you advise?

Comment: Well [`IServerXMLHttpRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762278(v=vs.85).aspx) was first released as part of MSXML 3.0 so we are talking 15 years or so ago, it was never designed to deal with IRIs only URIs not to mention [IRI wasn't defined until 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier).

Comment: Either COM component should serve the purpose, as I haven't used either I wouldn't like to comment.

Comment: @Lankymart rather than MSXML's age it must be something related to a Windows API that MSXML relies on. On Windows 10 I have no problem with IRIs for example. You know, builds matter a lot. Remember [this similar behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022415/serverxmlhttp-appending-to-content-type/35025129#35025129).

Comment: @Kul-Tigin I'd just be guessing, did my best detective work based on what I could find. Also agree it's probably OS related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made an amazing journey in to depth of my hard drive and found a code writen by / for [Jesper Høy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6334238/jesper-h%c3%b8y). This was the source code of SimpleDNS Plus' IDN Conversion Tool at that time.

Archive.org page snapshot: [http://www.simpledns.com/idn-convert.asp](http://web.archive.org/web/20060423164021/http://www.simpledns.com/idn-convert.asp)
Archive.org file snapshot: [idn-convert-asp.zip](http://web.archive.org/web/20060815234445/http://www.simpledns.com/outbox/idn-convert-asp.zip)

You can also copy the whole code from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/abd8b5f7763c912694da31f4ba97cc82).

Create a function to convert URLs.

```vb
Function DummyPuny(ByVal url)
    Dim rSegments : rSegments = Split(url, "/")

    If UBound(rSegments) > 1 Then
        rSegments(2) = DomainPunyEncode(rSegments(2))
    End If

    DummyPuny = Join(rSegments, "/")
End Function
```

Then convert your url before making the request.

```vb
XMLHttpReq.Open "GET", DummyPuny(url), False
```

Comment: This is awesome! I set out looking at writing a punycode implementation as I couldn't find one anywhere on the web for ASP, but stopped when I realised what was involved and just didn't have the time to get it right. Great answer!

Comment: @Lankymart Thanks. I'm glad you (and I of course) did not invent the wheel again.

Comment: Yeah. I did look at SimpleDNS Plus' IDN Conversion Tool but didn't realise it was originally written in ASP, otherwise I might have gone the WayBackMachine route.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I took non-HTML part from your ASP and it works as command line vbs as well!

Meanwhile to solve my problem I wrote C# tool which works nicely and consists of one lines (plus supportive staff):
`string convertedURL = uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Scheme | UriComponents.KeepDelimiter, UriFormat.UriEscaped) + uri.DnsSafeHost + uri.AbsolutePath;`